# How can i edit the link to the login on my comment note for a wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, authentication

Please I have surfed the web for this and I have not seen a helpful link.
I have a wordpress blog which a user must be logged in before he can comment on my posts.
Now my posts always have this note under every post when a user is not logged in

> You must be **loggedin** to post a comment

And the **loggedin** link points to the wordpress 'wp-login.php' page.

Now I already have a custom login page which I am using for other login purposes. So I want this link to point to my custom login page instead of the wordpress 'wp-login.php'

Or probably if there is a way I can redirect it to my custom login page.

Any link will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your `functions.php` :

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'your_login_page', 10, 2 );
function your_login_page( $login_url, $redirect ) {
    return home_url( '/your-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```

Above code will do the trick.

You can check WordPress Codex for [login_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_url#Description) filter.

Let me know the output.

Comment: You mean functions.php of my theme?